# make AppDelegate receive call back events from custom library

Tags: ios, objective-c, static-libraries, appdelegate

I'm trying to implement a library, but the library comes with minimal documentation and I'm a little out of my depth. By looking at other code I've got this far

Documentation says
*AppDelegate creates an object of JBLayer as a member variable*

So I did this in AppDelegate.h

```
#import "JBLayer.h"
//@class JBLayer;
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>
{
    JBLayer *aJBLayer;
}
@property (nonatomic, strong, readonly) JBLayer *aJBLayer;
```

this in AppDelegate.m

```
@implementation AppDelegate
@synthesize aJBLayer = _aJBLayer;
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    AppDelegate* appDelegate = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    // THIS IS WHERE I'm STUCK
    [aJBLayer SetHandler:self.doSetHandler];

    // This is what I have to include the lib for, this seems to be ok
    [aJBLayer MainCall];

    return YES;
}

-(id)doSetHandler
{
    return WHAT???;
}
```

The documentation says
*Set the handler the receive callback events by calling SetHandler. AppDelegate needs to pass self if AppDelegate wants to receive the call back events.*

Looking in the JBLayer.h file I find:

```
-(void)SetHandler:(id<interfaceJBHandler>)aHandler;
```

I have to implement these interfaceJBHandler methods which are in interfaceJBHandler.h

```
@protocol interfaceJBHandler
-(void)OnJBSuccess:(NSString *)aToken;
-(void)OnJBError:(NSError *)aError;
-(void)OnJBResponse :(NSData *)aData :(JBType )aTypeOfData;
```

I got as far as working out it's something like

```
[aJBLayer SetHandler:];
```

But everything I've tried gives errors

```
[aJBLayer SetHandler:self];
[aJBLayer SetHandler:appDelegate];
```

This compiles

```
[aJBLayer SetHandler:self.doSetHandler];
```

But I'm missing something, somewhere I have to make a delegate but up till now I've only done delegates to pas messages between viewcontrollers.

How do I make the AppDelegate receive the call back events?

Comment: what library is JBLayer from?

Comment: It's a custom library from client, comprised of a bunch of files including these three libJB.a, JBLayer.h, interfaceJBHandler.h

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass an object that implements the `interfaceJBHandler` protocol. If you want your appDelegate to be the object, change the following in the header file to make your app delegate conform to the protocol:

```
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate, interfaceJBHandler>
```

Set the delegate as your handler:

```
[aJBLayer SetHandler:self];
```

And implement the 3 required methods in your app delegate's implementation file:

```
-(void)OnJBSuccess:(NSString *)aToken{
    //Do Something
}

-(void)OnJBError:(NSError *)aError{
    //Do Something
}

-(void)OnJBResponse :(NSData *)aData :(JBType )aTypeOfData{
    //Do Something
}
```

Comment: Obvious. When told. Thanks